# Sharepoint 2013 VM slow start

Tags: sharepoint, virtual-machine, startup

I have an all-in-one sharepoint development environment. A single virtual machine with sql server, sharepoint and domain controller on it. The problem is that after restart the services take too much time to start. Besides the machine is rather slow overall. I know there are lots of stuff installed, but I don't believe it should have such an influence on the performane.
Are there any ways to check what is taking so long after restart? Any ways to speed things up?

Comment: what the performance caracterestics of your machine? RAM Process.. etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Virtual Machine on Hyper-V, try to disable dynamic memory.